# Why "errorCode" is empty in JSON of Kibana Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to ELK & Kibana dashboard where I would like to show ErrorCode in my JSON of Kibana dashboard which is coming as empty for my failure response from my API.

Do I need to make some code changes in my application or in Kibana ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here, I have attached one sample e.g. of my API (Failure Response) from Kibana Dashboard -

```
{
  "_index": "***-log.*****-2019.02.17",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "****XXXX*****",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "parentSpanId": "***********",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2019-02*****:15.211Z",
    "metrics": {},
    "stacktrace": "",
    "userSession": "",
    "environment": "XXX",
    "requester": "",
    "cmdbId": "",
    "transactionId": "",
    "executer": "",
    "executerSession": "",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "requesterSession": "",
    "errorTrail": "",
    "logger": "com.ing.mdm.exceptions.FaultResponseTransformer",
    "eventType": "QQQQ",
    "kafka.topic": "XYZ_topic",
    "schemaVersion": 1,
    "message": "Fault response occurred, error message: Received response from MDM for request: getAllXXXXYYYY, with message: The ***** was not found.",
    "component": "*****_API",
    "thread": "finagle/****2",
    "traceId": "*****20-9159******",
    "messages": [],
    "env": "dev",
    "spanId": "********8a7fd9",
    "timestamp": 1550400255211,
    "componentVersion": "02.00.0***",
    "user": "",
    **"errorCode": "",**
    "host": "XXXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ",
    "datacenter": "Anonymous",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "eventClass": "XYZ"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-02-17T10:44:15.211Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "component": [
      "@kibana*****@"
    ],
    "message": [
      "@kibana****@."
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    11111
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be few reasons:

1. Looks like the 'errorCode' field is empty in the document, so that might cause kibana not to detect the field type and therefore not display it properly.
2. If the field is new, kibana does not recognise its type. you will have to click "refresh field list" which is in Management -> index pattern menu (see screenshot) [image]

if that is not the case, please explain what is missing and where can't you see the field